# ASP.NET WebAPI filter data by user property

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

ASP.NET WebAPI 2.1

Here is my scenario:

- new user is registering (one of the Identity properties is CustomerID - hidden from user, default NULL)
- Admin is updating CustomerID with correct primary key from Customers table and assigning Role "Customer" to registered user. From now on user should be able to see all his Invoices, orders, etc.

How can I filter all web API calls for Invoices, Orders, etc with CustomerID ?

I was searching a lot and I couldn't find any samples. I'd really appreciate if some will point me to right direction and/or a sample code.

Below is my controller:

```
public class invoicesController : ApiController
{
    private myEntities db new db1Entities();

    // GET api/invoices
    public IQueryable<invoices> Getinvoices()
    {
           // here (I guess) I need to add a filter by CustomerID
               // first get CustomerID from logged In User

            return db.invoices;
    }

     // GET api/invoices/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(invoices))]
    public IHttpActionResult Getinvoices(int id)
     {
        invoices invoices_by_id = db.invoices.Find(id);
        if (invoices_by_id == null)
        {
                        return NotFound();
        }       
       return Ok(invoices_by_id);
    }   
}
```

OK. I got it working but I think there must a better way to access user property...anyone ?

```
// Instantiate the UserManager in ASP.Identity system to look up the user in the system
// ApplicationUser class is defined in IdentityModels.cs, same as ApplicationDbContext
var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
//Get the User object
var currentUser = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
//Get the profile information about the user
int? userCustomerID = currentUser.customerID;
```

And in controller I just changed last line:

```
return View(db.invoices.Where(i => i.CustomerID == userCustomerID).ToList());
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of this setup? Why isn't the `CustomerID` automatically set when registering? For the API, you want to search by CustomerID?

Comment: I don't see a simple, secure way to set CustomerID during registration. Customer was entered into database earlier using desktop application and user is registering later so I will have to recognize it somehow. I was thinking about creating such a function - for example ask the user to enter last invoice number and total amount - if user can answer correctly I could to automatic match. At this point let's assume we have valid CustomerID. How do I filter invoices by CustomerID ?

Comment: What does the DB structure look like?

Comment: You really need to state how you are authenticating users in your Web API. Are you using the new ASP.NET Identity system? Are you authenticating using cookies (via the web app), or are you authenticating against the API directly using a bearer token/basic auth?

Comment: I'm using Individual accounts and new Identity system / authentication using cookies. Tables belonging to Identity system are already added to my existing database (Table dbo.AspNetUsers). It is a "database First" approach.

Comment: So they are authenticating through an MVC controller?

Comment: OK. I got it working but I think there must be a better way to access logged in user property...